Equal angles are congruent, in an arbitrary symmetric bilinear space
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space with a symmetric bilinear form $B : V \times V \to F$. Consider two tuples $S = (u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n)$ and $T = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$, such that $$B(u_i, u_j) = B(v_i, v_j)$$ for all $i, j$. These are meant to represent a generalization of angles on $\mathbb R^2$. I want to find conditions on $B$ such that there exists some isomorphism $\varphi : V \to V$ with $T(u_i) = v_i$ that also preserves the bilinear form, meaning $B(\varphi(x), \varphi(y)) = B(x, y)$ for any $x, y \in V$. In other words, equal angles are congruent.
Partial progress:
This result is easy if both $S$ and $T$ are bases for $V$. If the quadratic form associated to $B$ is isotropic, meaning $B(x, x) = 0$ for some $x \ne 0$, this theorem fails, as $(0)$ can't be mapped over to $(x)$.
If $F = \mathbb R$, and both sets of vectors are linearly independent, I have a somewhat complicated proof of this fact. Extend $S$ by an orthonormal basis $S'$ for the orthogonal complement of its span, and likewise extend $T$ into $T'$. By Sylvester's law of inertia, both of these have the same amount of vectors with $B(x, x) \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$ respectively. Therefore, we can build a map with $\varphi(u_i) = v_i$ that maps $S'$ into $T'$, satisfying the problem conditions.
Over an arbitrary field, I don't know if this technique of completing a basis always works. It might be that there is some vector in $S'$ that can't be normalized into any vector in $T$, depending on how squares happen to behave over the field.
Edit:
The case where $S$ and $T$ are spanning sets is covered by Hugo's answer. With that in mind, I'd be fine simply having a characterization for the case where $S$ and $T$ are linearly independent.
I managed to prove that if $\dim(V) = 2$, $B$ is non-degenerate, $u, v \ne 0$ and $B(u, u) = B(v, v)$, then $u^\perp$ is isomorphic to $v^\perp$. If $B$ is non-isotropic, that means $u$ can be isometrically mapped onto $v$.

I wanted to find a counterexample for $S, T$ linearly independent and $B$ isotropic, so I tested out $F_5^2$ with the standard dot product. It just so happens, there are exactly $8$ automorphisms of this symmetric bilinear space, and there are exactly $8$ non-zero vectors with $B(v, v) = 0$. I have no idea how to explain this.

An orthogonal transformation $\phi$ preserves the bilinear form. This is easy to prove since $\langle \phi x , \phi y \rangle = \langle x, \phi^* \phi y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ from the definition $\phi^* \phi = \phi \phi^*= I$ of an orthogonal transformation ($I$ is the identity map $Iy=y$).

If $B$ is non-isotropic, then our desired mapping always exists. To see this, we only need to prove the case when $S$ and $T$ are linearly independent. In the general case, we can take bases $S' \subseteq S$ and $T' \subseteq T$ for their respective spans, map $S'$ to $T'$, and use Hugo's lemma to conclude $S$ is in fact mapped into $T$.
We induct on $n$. The result is trivial when $n = 0$. Suppose we now have $n + 1$ vectors in each of $S$ and $T$. By the inductive hypothesis, we define an isomorphism $\varphi_0 : V \to V$ (of symmetric bilinear spaces) with $\varphi_0(u_i) = v_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$. Let $W$ be the span of $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$. Write $$\varphi_0(u_{n+1}) = u + w_1,\quad v_{n + 1} = v + w_2$$ for $u, v \in W^\perp$ and $w_1, w_2 \in W$. For $1 \le i \le n$, we have $$B(w_1, v_i) = B(\varphi_0(u_{n+1}), \varphi_0(u_i)) = B(u_{n+1}, u_i) = B(v_{n+1}, v_i) = B(w_2, v_i),$$
which means $w_1 = w_2$. We write $w$ for the common value. Note that $$\begin{aligned}B(u, u) + B(w, w) &= B(u + w, u + w) = B(\varphi_0(u_{n+1}), \varphi_0(u_{n+1})) \\&= B(u_{n+1}, u_{n+1}) = B(v_{n+1}, v_{n+1}) = B(v, v) + B(w, w),\end{aligned}$$
so that $B(u, u) = B(v, v)$. We may thus define $\varphi_1 : W \to W$ as the reflection $$\varphi_1(x) = 2\frac{B(x, u + v)}{B(u + v, u + v)}(u + v) - x,$$
so that $\varphi_1(u) = v$. This can be extended into an isomorphism $\varphi_1 : V \to V$, which means $\varphi_1 \circ \varphi_0$ is our desired mapping.

Just to add a reference. Hugo's Lemma is called Stollen Carlos' lemma (see 4.8.1. Stollen Carlos’ lemma, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.0346).
It seems it is Stollen Hugo's lemma now.

This is the result I know.
Let $V$ be a vector spaces over $\mathbb k$. Assume that $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are generators for $V$.

If the bilinear form $g:V \times V \to \mathbb k$ is nondegenerate and
$g(u_i,u_j)=g(v_i,v_j)$, then there exists a linear isometry $\varphi:V \to V$ such that
$\varphi(u_i)=v_i$.

Indeed, define $$\varphi\left(\sum_i\alpha_i u_i\right) = \sum_i\alpha_i v_i.$$ We must show that this map is well defined, i.e., we must show that if
$$\sum_i\alpha_i u_i = \sum_i\beta_i u_i,$$ then
$$\sum_i\alpha_i v_i = \sum_i\beta_i v_i.$$
So, assume
$\sum_i\alpha_i u_i = \sum_i\beta_i u_i.$
For all $k$ we have
$$g\left(\sum_i\alpha_i u_i - \sum_i\beta_i u_i,u_k\right) = 0,$$
$$\sum_i(\alpha_i - \beta_i)g\left( u_i,u_k\right) = 0,$$
$$\sum_i(\alpha_i - \beta_i)g\left( v_i,v_k\right) = 0,$$
$$g\left(\sum_i\alpha_i v_i - \sum_i\beta_i v_i,v_k\right) = 0.$$
Therefore,
$$g\left(\sum_i\alpha_i v_i - \sum_i\beta_i v_i,y\right) = 0$$
for all $y \in V$ and since $g$ is nondenerate,
$$\sum_i\alpha_i v_i = \sum_i\beta_i v_i.$$
Thus, the map
$$\varphi\left(\sum_i\alpha_i u_i\right) = \sum_i\alpha_i v_i$$
is well-defined, linear, and isometry.

Nice. So just to make sure, the $u_i$ and $v_i$ don't have to be linearly independent? Just spanning sets.

Correct. They don't have to be linearly independent.
